# Variable label length in ZPL from cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, zebra-printers, zpl

I use phonegap/cordova plugin and Zebra iMZ320 to print by means of zpl containing text, images (converted on-the-fly to zpl) and a barcode. I have no mark or gap, so I need to use continuous mode. I cannot know in advance the length of what will be printed. So, how can I calculate the exact label length to pass it to the "^LL" command (I don't want to pass a maximum value because it would be a waste)? I would like to obtain the same thing as if line print were used (it stops right after printed).

Answer (score 1):

@Antonio you can calculate the content size beforehand based on the size of text (along with number of lines), size of images and bar-code. After that you can append that size in the "^LL" command directly.

For example :

I have 70 lines each line with size 30 so 70*30 = 2100 plus I have an image of length 400 so total size 2100 + 400 = 2500.

So I my code will look like:

```
^XA^LL2500
-----------
--Content--
-----------
^XZ
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: you could also send each line as if it were an individual label. That way you figure out the size of a line and then print. If you use ^MMR then you will not get the backfeed after each line. if you want cut then on the last line you can use ^MMC I believe.

Comment: How can I know in advance the size of the text since I used not-fixed font and field data ^FD is enclosed within a ^FB which has automatic word-wrap function?

Comment: @AntonioAtp I guess there is no definite way to know the length of your labels in advance. 

However, you can use a variable and dynamically calculate and add length of each label, image and barcode. Before printing you can set this variable in ^LL.

Comment: In fact my problem is in the text, not in images or barcodes. I would apply that way (dynamic calculation) if, before printing, I know how much lines the printer will produce. I should know the logic of word-wrap for FB (when will word-wrap be applied for a certain text and a certain font?). Or a sort of simulation to know the ^LL value. Am I over-complicating something which is not? After all: why "line print" mode stops after printing and "zpl" mode not?

Comment: @AntonioAtp There maybe an easier solution. I guess, we will have to try and see..

Comment: Same problem here: I am printing receipts on continuous paper featuring content with dynamic height (via ^TB text block and ^BQ QR codes) via Zebra ZPL on iOS/LinkOS/ZQ320 and there seems to be no way to get correct output without setting a label length first (which I don't know and cannot compute). Did anybody find a solution for this?